Generate OpenAPI documentation at build/compile time in SpringBoot 3.x application
I am running my application on Spring Boot 3.2.4 with Java 17. For generating Swagger/OpenAPI documentation, I am using Springdoc-OpenApi version 2.5.0. I came across the springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin which can generate the documentation, but it starts the application, generates the OpenAPI documentation, and then stops the application. This behavior is not suitable for my use case. I want to generate the OpenAPI documentation at build time without starting the application in any way.
Below is the dependencies I added in pom.xml :
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
          <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.0</version>
      </dependency>

      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.swagger.core.v3/swagger-annotations -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
          <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
          <version>2.2.21</version>
      </dependency>

      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.swagger.core.v3/swagger-models -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
          <artifactId>swagger-models</artifactId>
          <version>2.2.21</version>
      </dependency>

I have created a profile called "generate-swagger-client" and placed the necessary plugins inside it. To execute the profile, I use the command "mvn clean install -P generate-swagger-client". The command successfully generates the OpenAPI documentation, but it also starts and stops the application in the process. However, I want to generate the OpenAPI documentation at build time without starting the application.
Below is the plugins :
<profile>
    <id>generate-swagger-client</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Plugin for generating OpenAPI 3 documentation -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <jvmArguments>-Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true</jvmArguments>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>start</goal>
                            <goal>stop</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
                <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <apiDocsUrl>http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs</apiDocsUrl>
                    <outputFileName>openapi.json</outputFileName>
                    <outputDir>${basedir}/generated/swagger-specs</outputDir>
                    <skip>false</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
           
   

        

I want to generate the OpenAPI documentation at build time without starting the application in any way. How can i fix this ?
